# Deleted answers in newsletter

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, newsletter

Today I noticed this is the Meta Stack Exchange newsletter:

> [image]

I remembered [that answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308264/152859) was deleted more than 14 hours before that email was sent:

> [image]

I don't think we should see the "answered by" part if the answer is deleted.

Even if the newsletter check our reputation to see if we can view deleted posts (which I doubt), if the answer is deleted, it means it probably not really worth mentioning it in that context.

Comment: That's interesting, given that the answer in question was deleted just 12 minutes after it was posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

The queries that picked question id's to show filtered out deleted questions, but the query that found associated answers did not.